# Eclipse-Maven: Doesn't show Maven project from SCM

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven, version-control

I have installed the Maven plugin and the svn connector for sublipse. Afterwards I right clicked in the project explorer (empty workspace) and clicked *New -> Other -> Maven -> Maven project from SCM*, entered the URL and it started downloading.

After download finished, it didn't show up in the "Project-Explorer". What do I have to do, in order to checkout a Maven project from SVN so it shows up in the "Project-Explorer".

Comment: Temporary workaround - select *File > Import... > Maven > Existing Maven Projects* and navigate to the folder where your pom.xml file has been checked out to.

Comment: I've tried it, but it's running since an hour, and it still didn't import. Import is analysing pom files, but that's very very slow.

Comment: When you say you have installed the svn connector for subclipse do you mean the one that is in the m2eclipse-extras update site (http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras)?

Comment: @gwhitake I found the connector trough the Eclipse Marketplace. I had some proxy problems. Now importing almost works, except I get errors stating plugins like maven scr could not be found. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the "Checkout as Maven Project" functionality to work I have had to install the following:

From the Eclipse Marketplace:

1. Maven Integration for Eclipse
2. Subclipse

From the m2eclipse-extras update site (http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras/):

1. Maven SCM handler for Subclipse

EDIT:

Also make sure that your project explorer view is setup correctly.  Verify that your top level items are projects.