# Eclipse Maven: no "Checkout Maven project from SCM" option

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I have to compile and run a Maven project that some colleagues of mine developed some years ago. I'm using Eclipse Helios on Microsoft Windows Server 2008.

In their documentation about how to compile it with Eclipse, I read that I have to install on my Eclipse:

- Maven plugin (from http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e )
- Maven plugin extra (from http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras )
- Subclipse plugin ( http://subclipse.tigris.org )

After installed these plugins, their document says to select the option "Checkout Maven Project from SCM" and other operations.

I've tried to install these plugins, but, first, I realized that they are antiquated.
I discovered that Maven Plugin changed name and address (now is Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.2), and that Maven Plugin Extra does not exist anymore.
Subclipse, instead, is available.

So I installed these plugins, but, afterwords, no  "Checkout Maven Project from SCM" functionality was present on my Eclipse.
Then I searched online to solve this problem, and I found [this thread on StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192393/eclipse-maven-doesnt-show-maven-project-from-scm). It suggested to install the **Maven SCM handler for Subclipse**.
I've searched it on the plugin repository of Elcipse **but it does not exist anymore.**

Which Eclipse plugin may I use to get the "Checkout Maven Project from SCM" functionality on my Eclipse IDE ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 29):

When you go to Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Discovery, you have a button "Open Catalog", which opens a plugin marketplace specific to the m2e plugin. There you'll find a plugin called m2e-subclipse, which should give you the appropriate options:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I cannot find an item "Maven" on my preference menu! Why?

Comment: Have you installed the plugin "Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.2"?

Comment: Yes, I've installed it... :-(

Comment: Davide, can you go to Help : Install New Software... then click on the "What is already installed?" link on the right side of the check boxes area. Find m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse. What's in the Version column?

Answer (score 2):

Change the installed sub version to have m2 plugin. then check out as maven shows up.

**Eclipse Marketplace -> Installed -> Subversive SVN -> Change -> Subversive SVN Integration for the M2E Project (Optional) and install it.**

see images below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have recently run into same issue and found solution, as preferences trick mentioned in this post did not work for me.
All you need to do is to go back to your SVN installation (tested for subversive, guess similar for subclipse) and check m2e integration plug-in.

In my case: Eclipse Marketplace -> Installed -> Subversive SVN -> Change -> Subversive SVN Integration for the M2E Project (Optional) and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround , since I was not able to find m2e-subclipse in Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Discovery.You need to check out the project.Once done, right click on the Project Explorer and Import->Maven->Existing Maven Project and select the checked out project and click Finish.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up for anybody seeing this again for future versions of Eclipse.

Sonatype is no longer maintaining this:

You can either use the fork currently being maintainted in github [https://github.com/subclipse/m2e]:
https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/m2e/1.0.x/

Or you can use the eclipse maintained link for the eclipse version:
https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.9/1.9.1.20180912-1601/

Install either one by using the "install new software" link in Eclipse above "Eclipse Marketplace"

[image: Eclipse installation]

Answer (score 0):

I used eclipse version 2022-12 from this website https://mergedoc.osdn.jp/
After I face this problem and try many ways. Finally, I got the solution.

1. Right-click on repo
2. Select **Find/Check Out As...**
3. Choose **Check out as a project with the name specified**, then input your project name alias
4. After checkout is finished. Right-click on the project.
5. Select **Configure > Convert to Maven Project**.